# Need a stored procedure that inserts a row and returns the ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to write a stored procedure that first inserts a new record into table and then returned the id of this new record. I am not sure if it is the correct way and the best way to achieve this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spAddAsset
(
@Name VARCHAR(500),
@URL VARCHAR(2000)
)
AS
BEGIN
Set NOCOUNT on;

Insert Into Assets (Name, URL) Values (@Name, @URL)

Declare @new_identity int;

SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

return @new_identity;
END
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To return a single scalar value to the caller you should use an `OUTPUT` parameter, not `RETURN`. `RETURN` is for error/status codes. Also the prefix sp is redundant and unnecessary.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddAsset
  @Name VARCHAR(500),
  @URL  VARCHAR(2000),
  @new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.Assets(Name, URL) SELECT @Name, @URL;
    SET @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

Then to call it:

```
DECLARE @new_identity INT;
EXEC dbo.AddAsset @Name = 'a', @URL = 'b', @new_identity = @new_identity OUTPUT;
PRINT @new_identity;
```

**EDIT** just adding a disclaimer that won't affect the asker in this specific scenario, but may help in other scenarios or for future readers. In SQL Server 2008 R2 and earlier, there is a [potentially nasty bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) with built-in functions such as `SCOPE_IDENTITY` when parallelism is used to derive the results to be inserted (think `INSERT FROM othertable`). This bug ([here is the Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value)) is fixed in [Cumulative Update #5 for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659694), but so far a fix has not appeared for 2008 R2 RTM, 2008 or 2005.

Comment: hi, how do I return the set of multiple records that I added ( I have XML as input source) ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why it is necessary to place the returned row value into a new variable `@new_identity`. I would simply include `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` at the end of the stored procedure like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddAsset
  @Name VARCHAR(500),
  @URL  VARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.Assets(Name, URL) SELECT @Name, @URL;
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```