# Stored procedure always return 1

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I've been fighting with this for at least two hours and since my knowledge of MSSql is very limited wanted to ask for help:

```
val action: DBIO[Seq[Int]] = sql"""
  DECLARE @id int;
  EXEC AdsContent.TemplatesCreate
    @ID_ClientSites  = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.idClientSites},
    @Title = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.title},
    @FileName = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.fileName},
    @Description1 = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.description},
    @Description2 = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.description},
    @DID_BannerElementStatus = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.didBannerElementStatus},
    @TemplateVersion = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.templateVersion},
    @ID_AgencyUsers  = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.idAgencyUser},
    @IsReadOnly = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.readOnly},
    @CanBeUsedInProductTargeting = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.canBuUsedInProductionTargeting},
    @ID_OwnedBy = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.ownedBy},
    @ID_CreatedBy = ${bannerElementTemplatesDto.createdById},
    @ID_BannerElementTemplates = @id OUTPUT;
  select @id as 'id'
  """.as[Int]

db.run(action).map { x =>
  x match {
    case Seq() => throw new SQLException("No id was returned from the when inserting template to DB")
    case Seq(a) => a
    case Seq(xs @ _*) => throw new SQLException(s"Multiple values were returned when inserting template to DB: $xs")
  }
}
```

Well this compiles and it can insert data into the database but I cannot get the generated id.

The id is associated with `@ID_BannerElementTemplates` and set in the procedure this way:

```
SELECT @ID_BannerElementTemplates = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I always get `1` as result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557603/need-a-stored-procedure-that-inserts-a-row-and-returns-the-id

Comment: what's the output if you run the query from SSMS or similar tools?